# Ajax File Managerv Tinymce: How to change relative image url to absolute image in editor

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE with Ajax File Manager extension (http://www.phpletter.com/demo/tinymce-ajax-file-manager/).

All shows up fine, but when I go through the image button to upload and add an image to my WSYIWYG field, the image path look like

```
<img src="../../../images/hero.jpg" alt="" />
```

What I need to be getting is the following:

```
<img src="http://localhost/image/hero.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to change the "relative_urls : true" to "relative_urls : false" in tinyMCE.init

```
tinyMCE.init({
  relative_urls : false,
});
```